# What does "conditional inclusion" mean in C programming?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When programming with C, I encountered a concept "conditional inclusion" in relation to the C preprocessor. I tried to understand this concept by referring to a few web pages, but so far I haven't been able to get a clear idea of what is being referred to.

Might someone explain this concept along with an example?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional ?

Comment: Close voters: Basic questions *can* be valid questions for SO.

Comment: For inclusions: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax for conditionals: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Conditionals.html#Conditionals

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But not without research.

Comment: @H2CO3: Meh, there are plenty of questions with a similar level of apparent research left open, upvoted, and usefully answered.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's sad and it should not be the case.

Comment: @H2CO3: I think you're being too critical, frankly. SO is meant to be helpful. The OP says he's looked at a couple of sites and not been able to follow what they said. Given the topic (the C preprocessor), that seems pretty easy to believe, to me. Best,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : yes , u are correct and really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code which uses the `#ifdef` preprocessor directive (standing for `#if defined`).

```
#ifdef FLAG1
#include "header1.h"
#endif
```

Now, when you compile, if `FLAG1` is defined (either because of the architecture or via `-D` flag -- as in `gcc -DFLAG1 source.c`) `header1` will be included. Same for

```
#ifdef FLAG1
// any valid C code
#endif
```

For example, one might use them to have a cross-platform implementation (example trimmed down) -- `__linux__` is defined only if compiling on Linux while `_WIN32` only if compiling on Windows:

```
#ifdef __linux__ /* "If the __linux__ preprocessor variable is defined..." */

    #define select_os select_linux
    #define spawn_os spawn_linux

    typedef int pidtype;
    typedef int fdtype;

#elif defined (_WIN32) /* "Else, if the _WIN32 preprocessor variable is defined..." */

    #include <windows.h>

    #define select_os select_windows
    #define spawn_os spawn_windows

    #define strdup _strdup

    typedef HANDLE pidtype;
    typedef int fdtype;

#endif
```

*(The indentation is just for clarity, people usually leave it out.)*

To the user of this API (the code including this file) the functions looks the same no matter the OS the code is compiled on.